# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError during service startup with kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud

I am trying to make a small microservices project to touch kafka.
To start kafka I am using docker compose:

```
  kafka-server:
image: spotify/kafka
ports:
- 2181:2181
- 9092:9092
environment:
  ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
  CONSUMER_THREADS: 1
  TOPICS: serverInputTopic,clientInputTopic
```

To add kafka support in my service I use following in POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Only usage in code is annotation on runner class

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
```

and annotation on listener method

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
```

I start kafka without problems, but when I start my service I get following error:

```
    ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: F
ailed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties.setAuthorizationExceptionRetryInterval(Ljava/time/Duration;)V
```

What can be done to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved with external dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue as reported here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/issues/70

You need to upgrade the version of Spring Integration Kafka to 2.1.0 to fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, this is different issue. And I already have spring-integration-kafka:3.2.1.RELEASE